# Is it possible to access channels ch1, ch2 using `select` in Golang?

Tags: go, methods, struct

I was trying to debug this code but am stuck here. I wanted to access ch1, ch2 but found printed nothing.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type degen struct {
    i, j string
}

func (x degen) CVIO(ch1, ch2 chan string, quit chan int, m, n string) {
    for {
        select {
        case ch1 <- m:
            fmt.Println(x.i)
        case ch2 <- n:
            fmt.Println("ok")
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }

}

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan string)
    ch2 := make(chan string)
    quit := make(chan int)
    x := degen{"goosebump", "ok"}
    go x.CVIO(ch1, ch2, quit, "goosebump", "ok")
}
```

Desired:
It should print the channel data as to be produced.

Comment: You did not give the goroutine any chance to look for inputs on any of its channels. The main routine will exit right after starting the goroutine

Comment: 1. You program ends before it does anything sensible. 2. Nobody is reading on the channels so you cannot send. 3. You cannot "access" a channel, all you can do is send and receive from it and _both_ have to happen on unbuffered channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not really clear what you expect your code to do:

- `main()` ends without waiting for the go routine to exit (its quite possible it the loop will not run at all).
- in the `select` the sends will not proceed because there is no receiver ([spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) - "if the capacity is zero or absent, the channel is unbuffered and communication succeeds only when both a sender and receiver are ready.").
- Nothing is sent to the `quit` channel.

I suspect that the following ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DqfH5ItJFk3)) might do what you were expecting.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type degen struct {
    i, j string
}

func (x degen) CVIO(ch1, ch2 chan string, quit chan int, m, n string) {
    for {
        select {
        case ch1 <- m:
            fmt.Println(x.i)
        case ch2 <- n:
            fmt.Println("ok")
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }

}

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan string)
    ch2 := make(chan string)
    quit := make(chan int)
    x := degen{"goosebump", "ok"}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        x.CVIO(ch1, ch2, quit, "goosebump", "ok")
        wg.Done()
    }()

    <-ch1 // Receive from CH1 (allowing "ch1 <- m" in go routine to proceed)
    <-ch2 // Receive from CH2 (allowing "ch2 <- n" in go routine to proceed)

    quit <- 1
    wg.Wait() // Wait for CVIO to end (which it should do due to above send)
}
```